# Stop XML::Smart from interpreting CDATA

Tags: xml, perl, cdata

I'm trying to parse an xml file that has entries like:

```
<ANNOTATION_VALUE>&lt;unk&gt;</ANNOTATION_VALUE>
<TIER LINGUISTIC_TYPE_REF="default-lt" TIER_ID="&lt;Target>"/>
```

Unfortunately, XML::Smart sees these and thinks they are CDATA tags. When I save the xml data, it turns into this:

```
<ANNOTATION_VALUE><![CDATA[<unk>]]></ANNOTATION_VALUE>
<TIER LINGUISTIC_TYPE_REF="default-lt">
<TIER_ID><![CDATA[<Target>]]></TIER_ID>
</TIER>
```

I tried to stop this by setting set_cdata(false) on all the nodes, but it doesn't seem to change anything:

```
$xml->{TIER}{TIER_ID}->set_cdata(0);
$xml->{ANNOTATION_VALUE}->set_cdata(0);
```

How can I get XML::Smart to stop reading these as CDATA?

Comment: Well, I solved my own problem by switching to XML::LibXML, which processed the data with no problems. I guess XML::Smart is too smart for its own good! It would still be nice to know if there's a better way to solve this problem.

Comment: the fact that TIER_ID goes from being an attribute to being an element _is_ a problem. But whether the data in an element is wrapped in a CDATA section or escaped using entities should not matter one bit to any proper XML processor.